# Image tag with a background-size style

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension

I was going through the code of a certain theme on gmail. I notice that the image width on render is set as follows:

`<img src="abc.jpg" style="width:1400px;">`

My question is, can I change this to

`style="background-size: cover;`?

I'm asking because i'm working on a chrome extension that tends to mess up the resizing of the image on window resize and I would like to know if I can set this image style to background-size. I know for certain that my code is not making any changes to the script that runs the theme but for some reason it's still happening.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is an img-tag and not a background you can't apply `background-size: cover` to it.

You can wrap the image with div and add the img src to it and apply the background-cover to the div.

Or you can play with min-width and min-height of the image in order to do something close to cover effect.